# Adding spaces after combining 3 inputs

Tags: php

I had 3 input field and I want to combine it all. I had this code but I don't know how to add spaces after combining them.

```
$user_name1=$_POST['user_name1']; //first name
$user_name2=$_POST['user_name2']; //middle name
$user_name3=$_POST['user_name3']; //last name
$user_name= $user_name1.$user_name2.$user_name3; //complete name
$user_name = ucwords($user_name);
```

My output: JamesRainAvilla

My expected output: James Rain Avilla

Any suggestion or help please?

Comment: $user_name= $user_name1 . ' ' . $user_name2 . ' ' . $user_name3;

Comment: Please read some basics of php.

Comment: start with this... http://www.w3schools.com/php/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should concatenate with "space"

```
$user_name= $user_name1." ".$user_name2." ".$user_name3;
```

Ref: [PHP String](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)